# Does anyone know how to create two parallel tables using iText in JAVA?

Tags: java, itext

I already created table using iText in java. But I want to create two parallel tables for one of my projects. Can anyone tell me the solution to create two parallel tables using iText please?

Comment: You can try having one table with two columns and each cell contains one table. Set the NO_BORDER property for the cells of the outer table. This way you will have parallel tables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code snippet

```
package com.example;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class PdfTest {

    private Document document;

    public PdfTest() {
        document = new Document();
    }

    public boolean openPdf() {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            File pdfFile = new File("test.pdf");
            if (pdfFile != null) {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
                document.open();
                status = true;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void closePdf() {
        document.close();
    }

    public void generatePdf() throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        // Main table
        PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        mainTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
        // First table
        PdfPCell firstTableCell = new PdfPCell();
        firstTableCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPTable firstTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        firstTable.setWidthPercentage(50.0f);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T1R1C1"));
        firstTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T1R1C2"));
        firstTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T1R2C1"));
        firstTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T1R2C2"));
        firstTable.addCell(cell);
        firstTableCell.addElement(firstTable);
        mainTable.addCell(firstTableCell);
        // Second table
        PdfPCell secondTableCell = new PdfPCell();
        secondTableCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPTable secondTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        secondTable.setWidthPercentage(50.0f);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T2R1C1"));
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T2R1C2"));
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T2R2C1"));
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T2R2C2"));
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
        secondTableCell.addElement(secondTable);
        mainTable.addCell(secondTableCell);
        paragraph.add(mainTable);
        document.add(paragraph);
    }
}
```

Test this with

```
PdfTest pdfTest = new PdfTest();
try {
    if (pdfTest.openPdf()) {
        pdfTest.generatePdf();
        pdfTest.closePdf();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much. this was the one i looked for. this helped me a lot. thank you again

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the [column_table.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/column_table.pdf) document. Starting on page 3, you'll see that the pages have a layout with two columns next to each other. This is achieved by using the `ColumnText` class. See [ColumnTable](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=91) for the source code or look at other code samples by going to the keyword page for [`ColumnText`](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=59).